# Oracle query to filter and sort table based on values in child table

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, java-stream

I am using Oracle 11g, and I have tables with data and structure as follows:

```
TABLE1_PARENT:
-------------------
PID | Name  | Age |
-------------------
 1 | Mark   | 35  |
 2 | Jane   | 40  |
 3 | Agatha | 45  |
-------------------


TABLE2_CHILD
==============================================
CID | Name       | Age | Class | House | PID |
----------------------------------------------
 1 | John        | 7  |    3   | Red   |  1  |
 2 | Marie       | 5  |    1   | Yellow|  2  |
 3 | Petra       | 6  |    2   | Green |  3  |
 4 | Taylor      | 8  |    4   | Blue  |  2  |
 5 | Lean        | 9  |    5   | Red   |  2  |
 6 | Justin      | 7  |    3   | Yellow|  3  |
 7 | Arianna     | 5  |    1   | Blue  |  3  |
 8 | Brendon     | 6  |    2   | Green |  3  |
 9 | Shawn       | 7  |    3   | Red   |  1  |
----------------------------------------------
```

For a single condition, the query is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1_PARENT WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID FROM TABLE2_CHILD WHERE AGE=7);
```

which will result in the following result:

```
TABLE1_PARENT:
-------------------
PID | Name  | Age |
-------------------
 1 | Mark   | 35  |
 3 | Agatha | 45  |
-------------------
```

However, if I want to fetch the list of parents whose children are of age=7 and belong to house='GREEN', if I write a query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1_PARENT WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID FROM TABLE2_CHILD WHERE AGE=7 AND house='GREEN');
```

I would get no results.

I am expecting the result to be :

```
TABLE1_PARENT:
-------------------
PID | Name  | Age |
-------------------
 3 | Agatha | 45  |
-------------------
```

since Agatha has a child belonging to age=7, and a child belonging to house='GREEN'.

I was able to come up with a solution for a similar data structure using Java streams. I am trying to do the same using Oracle SQL.

```
List<Parent> filteredParents = parents.stream()
                .filter(parent -> parent.getChildren().stream()
                        .anyMatch(child -> child.getAge().equals("7")) && parent.getChildren().stream()
                        .anyMatch(child -> child.getHouse().equalsIgnoreCase("Green")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am expecting the query to give me a result where the conditions could match any of the children. Because, the filtering is happening at the Parent level.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1_PARENT WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID FROM TABLE2_CHILD IF AGE=7 AND house='GREEN');` inside the subquery you use `IF` and I think you have to use `WHERE`

Comment: @Level_Up Thank you for pointing it out. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM TABLE1_PARENT t
WHERE t.PID IN (
  SELECT PID FROM TABLE2_CHILD WHERE AGE=7
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2_CHILD WHERE PID = t.PID AND House = 'Green'
)
```

The problem with your query is that it tries to apply both conditions in the same row inside `TABLE2_CHILD`. But this is not what you want. 
You want the parent ids for which children rows have `AGE = 7` and there is a row inside `TABLE2_CHILD` with `House = 'Green'`.
You could use EXISTS for both conditions, which may be more efficient:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM TABLE1_PARENT t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2_CHILD WHERE PID = t.PID AND AGE=7
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2_CHILD WHERE PID = t.PID AND House = 'Green'
)
```

or with conditional aggregation by grouping the child table by `PID`:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1_PARENT
WHERE PID IN (
  SELECT PID
  FROM TABLE2_CHILD 
  GROUP BY PID
  HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN House = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
)
```

Comment: If I apply this logic on a large dataset, say tables with millions of records. Would it cause a performance issue?

Comment: *with millions of records* there is always *a performance issue*. Try it and by using the proper indexes, say for Age and House you can find the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting output because in your TABLE2_CHILD, there is no child whose age is 7 in the green house. For your expected result, the query should be:

SELECT * FROM TABLE1_PARENT WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID FROM TABLE2_CHILD WHERE AGE=7) AND PID IN (SELECT PID FROM TABLE2_CHILD WHERE house='GREEN');

Comment: This would work. But I'm trying to use this on a very large dataset. Would this affect the performance?

Comment: This will not affect the performance since this is the simplest way to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the parent who have a child with age = 7, and the same child belongs to house=GREEN, use the query you already wrote:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1_PARENT WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID FROM TABLE2_CHILD IF AGE=7 AND house='GREEN');`

If you want to get the parent whose children either has age=7 or house=GREEN or both, use

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1_PARENT WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID FROM TABLE2_CHILD IF AGE=7 OR house='GREEN');`

Comment: This query would return both Mark and Agatha. I am trying to filter at the parent level. So the parents should have a child whose age=7 and a child whose house='Green'. This doesn't have to be the same child. But the parent should have a child meeting both criteria.